# I want to check the permission of folder in php

Tags: php

videos_comm is my folder in upload folder and I want to check its permission in php .

```
$path = "/var/www/upload/videos_comm/";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileperms()` is used in PHP to get file permissions.

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms("/var/www/upload/videos_comm/")), -4);
```

Please refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fileperms()` function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

`echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($path)), -4);`

Will show you the octal value of the file permissions.